# keydown event not bound for dynamic select2 elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

This is not a duplicate question.
There are many `select2` elements on page that are dynamically generated.
I need to capture the enter key press and the `keydown` event is not being bound to them.
The `keyup` event works fine though.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ky097s1/9/

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", ".select2-search__field", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log(200);
      }

});
```

Comment: Your previous question already contains the answer and a working example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Keydown isn't working for dynamic elements. Hence this question. Pls check the fiddle. I have updated the previous question.

Comment: It's not dynamic if you attach the event handler after you instantiate the `select2()` plugin, as the previous answer shows: https://jsfiddle.net/3f7j6hp8/

Comment: In that example it isnt dynamic...but in my page it is

Comment: The point is that the `keydown` event is swallowed by the Select2 library somewhere, presumably they call `stopPropagation` somewhere on that event. As such you cannot assign it dynamically. That is why you need to assign a standard event handler *after* you instantiate the library.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah so that must be it. But i was unable to capture the enter key press in the keyup event too and seems keydown was the only way. Could you  pls suggest of an alternative or how to assign a std. event.

Comment: IT's all in the previous answer and the fiddle I showed you above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189580/discussion-between-qwerty-and-rory-mccrossan).